# retrieving array from mysql and iterating through that array

Tags: php, oop

below is a php object which is retrieving some values from mysql db through a php method

```
$query = "SELECT imgpath from images";

$oMySQL->ExecuteSQL($query);
```

Now when i use this

```
$result=$oMySQL->ExecuteSQL($query);
```

it prints "Array" 
How to iterate through the array

Regards Jane

Comment: I think you should review the basis of PHP.

Comment: Can you post that array. use `for` or `foreach` to iterate `array`

Comment: use `foreach` or `for` in php and iterate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple foreach loop.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $val) {
      foreach ($val as $label => $item) {
            echo $label . " - " . $item;
      }
}
```

`$key` will hold the associative name the array element, and `$val` will hold the value of the element.

Comment: @DevZero it prints    0 - Array1 - Array2 - Array3 - Array4 - Array5 - Array6 - Array not the values

Comment: @JaneMarjana instead of `echo`, use `print_r` or `var_dump` functions

Comment: @JaneMarjana then you must loop again let me update my answer

Answer (score 2):

You mean it print array when you do echo $result?

Then:

```
foreach($result as $index => $value) {
   echo $index . '=' $value;
}
```